# How to loop checkbox for each value in dropdown list in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

```js
data() {
    return {
      selected: [],
    }
    watch: {
      selected(val) {
        this.$emit("checked", val);
      },
    },
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>State:</span>
  <select :disabled="listCities.length == 0" v-model="selectedCity">
    <option value="">Select a City</option>
    <option v-for="(city, index) in listCities" :key="index" :value="city.city_name">
      {{ city.city_name }}
      //<input type="checkbox" :id="index" :value="city.city_name" v-model="selected" />
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

How to loop checkbox for each value in dropdown list in vuejs?

Basically i have a dropdown, where i can able to select list of cities available based on the state.
So, Once i get the cities, i should be able to select multiple of them and display the number of selected cities.(by placing checkboxes for each value from city dropdown list, and display the number of selected cities)

[Codesandbox link working](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-bush-yxfc8?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Checkboxes inside selects is not valid html so you're going to have problems. What UI/UX are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @bassxzero i want to achieve like, Once i get the cities from the dropdown liat, i should be able to select multiple of them and display the number of selected cities.

Comment: This is my codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-bush-yxfc8?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Have you thought about using a multi select?\

Comment: @bassxzero if possible can you please provide some code, on how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      listCities: [{city_name: 'name 1'}, {city_name: 'name 2'}, {city_name: 'name 3'}, {city_name: 'name 4'}, {city_name: 'name 5'}, {city_name: 'name 6'}],
      selectedCity: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectCity(city) {
      this.selectedCity.includes(city) ? this.selectedCity = this.selectedCity.filter(s => s !== city) : this.selectedCity.push(city)
    },
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```css
.city__list {
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="demo" class="dropdown">
  <span>Cities:</span>
  <ul class="city__list">
    <li v-for="(city, index) in listCities" :key="index" >
      <input id="chk" type="checkbox" :value="city.city_name" @click="selectCity(city.city_name)" />
      {{ city.city_name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span>Selected Cities:</span>
  <p>{{ selectedCity }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have already done this, but only issue is i was unable to place checkbox  for each list available in dropdown.